# Mongodb connect error using .net core 2.2

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using mongodb and .net core 2.2 web api. When i run on my local machine I am getting following error

> A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "Automatic", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/localhost:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/localhost:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoAuthenticationException: Unable to authenticate using sasl protocol mechanism SCRAM-SHA-1. ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command saslStart failed: Authentication failed..
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingQueryMessageWireProtocol`1.ProcessReply(ConnectionId connectionId, ReplyMessage`1 reply)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingQueryMessageWireProtocol`1.ExecuteAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.SaslAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(IConnection connection, ConnectionDescription description, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.SaslAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(IConnection connection, ConnectionDescription description, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.DefaultAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(IConnection connection, ConnectionDescription description, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.AuthenticationHelper.AuthenticateAsync(IConnection connection, ConnectionDescription description, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.InitializeConnectionAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.HeartbeatAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)" }] }.

Comment: Do you have a question to accompany your stack trace?

Comment: @john actually deployed on IIS 10 and calling API using postman.

Comment: ... OK. That's not a question either.

Comment: A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector, this tells you the story, you are doing some stuff that takes long time and it fails at some point. The only question is here what are you trying to do I can not answer that hence I am missing a lot of details. like what, how many records, are they indexed, etc. I will vote to close this question.

Comment: Thanks all. This is closed. problem is with the admin user credentials

Answer (score -1):

This is failing to connect to mongodb. Try running queries with your local mongodb (I assume this is where your mongodb is set up) first.

Comment: You missed the last comment on the question, where the user reported to have found the problem.

Comment: The timeout also occurs if the mongodb connection cannot be accessed within the network. For those who might be entering the right credentials and stil encountering timeout, I placed this answer.